# \n is not creating a new line between text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript that is supposed to update a  in my HTML:

```
var StringContent = ({
    "a": 'Some String a',
    "b": 'Some string b',
    "c": 'Some string c',
});
```

Then I want each string a, b, c displayed on a new line via:

```
document.getElementById("overlaycontent").innerHTML = (
    StringContent.a + '\n' +
    StringContent.b + '\n' +
    StringContent.c,
    )
```

All I get at the moment is everything in a single line.  How do I create a new line in my text without adding more `div`s?  I also tried `\r`, but that also does not help.  I looked at the docs, but it keeps saying to use `\n`.

Comment: In HTML, you should use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Or use a `class` or block element and let CSS do the work.

Comment: The generated text will have new lines, however, under most situations, white space is collapsed with HTML.  This is why you are seeing the recommendation to use `<br>`.  You could also generate conteint within `<pre>` tags which do respect the white space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `\n` by `<br>` since `innerHTML` takes an HTML string (in HTML, `\n` merges with adjacent spaces but does not produce a carriage return except for elements with the style `white-space:pre-wrap` as noted by MaxArt) :

```
document.getElementById("overlaycontent").innerHTML = (
    StringContent.a + '<br>' +
    StringContent.b + '<br>' +
    StringContent.c,
)
```

Comment: I would say `can` rather than `should`

Comment: It's not that "`\n` means nothing", but rather whitespaces are collapsed to a single space, unless you set the CSS `white-space` property to `pre` or other variants.

Answer (score 2):

CSS! `white-space`! `pre-wrap`! Learn about it!

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">




                       SPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACE!

Newlines totally work now!
</div>
```

Comment: That's quite an enthusiatic endorsement of CSS.

Comment: @MaxArt Hehe... well, it's such a useful feature... People need to know!

Comment: This way you can even read the text back and do not have to replace `<br>` with a `\n` to get back to the original, bonus. :)

Comment: And several spaces in a row works too - great if you're trying to do any kind of indent for whatever reason, and for basic ASCII art!

Comment: Nope, let's choose the sucky way. :P

Answer (score 1):

for innerHTML you need `'<br />'`

```
document.getElementById("overlaycontent").innerHTML = (
    StringContent.a + '<br />' +
    StringContent.b + '<br />' +
    StringContent.c
    )
```

but for an alert you can use  : `String.fromCharCode(10)` instead of `'\n'`

```
alert(
    StringContent.a + String.fromCharCode(10) +
    StringContent.b + String.fromCharCode(10) +
    StringContent.c
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` (or sometimes `\r\n`) will work when outputting to a text element such as `<textarea>` or to a `.txt` document, but `<br>` is required for HTML.